# How to return up to five occurrences of a string in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, search, text

I have a task which involves a user entering a string. Then my program needs to return up to five occurrences of this string from a text file, subsequently then saving these lines to a separate file.

This is my code:
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LvCk.png)

However, I do not know how to alter this so that it returns up to 5 occurrences of the string, and no more.

Many thanks, AB

Comment: Please include the code in your question, not a link to an image which may expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise a counter and add to five. Exit when five...

```
Count=0
for line is search_file:
    if searchspec in line:
        #write to file
        Count+=1
    if count == 5:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re

input_string = input("Search Criteria : ")

with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as input_file:

data = input_file.read()

if len(re.findall(input_string, data)) == 5:

    for line in data.split('\n'):

        if input_string in line:

            with open('fiveoccurrences.txt', 'a+') as out_file:

                out_file.write(line+'\n')
```